# How can i display my pieseries item name inside RADCHART

Tags: asp.net, rad, radchart

I have pieseries items as item1,item2,item3,item4 and item5.I had attached an image of the below code.How can i display my pieseries item name inside chart?

CODE:

```
 <telerik:RadHtmlChart ID="RadHtmlChart1" runat="server">
        <PlotArea>
            <Series>
                <telerik:PieSeries Name="PieSeries1" StartAngle="90">
                    <SeriesItems>
                        <telerik:PieSeriesItem Y="1" Name="item1" />
                        <telerik:PieSeriesItem Y="2" Name="item2" />
                        <telerik:PieSeriesItem Y="3" Name="item3" />
                        <telerik:PieSeriesItem Y="4" Name="item4" />
                        <telerik:PieSeriesItem Y="5" Name="item5" />
                    </SeriesItems>
                    <LabelsAppearance Visible="False" />
                </telerik:PieSeries>
            </Series>
        </PlotArea>
    </telerik:RadHtmlChart>
```

Snapshot:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your `LabelsAppearance` to Visible, and Position: Center

```
<telerik:PieSeries Name="PieSeries1" StartAngle="90">
                <SeriesItems>
                  ...
                </SeriesItems>
                <LabelsAppearance Visible="True">
                     <Position="Center"/>
                </LabelsAppearance>

            </telerik:PieSeries>
```

https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/htmlchart/examples/charttypes/piechart/defaultcs.aspx

Comment: Position is a property of LabelsAppearance, not a child.Also, this just displays the Y value, not the Item name as requested. I am also trying to figure out how to get the name inside the pie slices.